# Chapter -1 , Exercise-1 , Question-1 : Higher Algebra by Barnard and Child

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've completed my higher school last week and I'm trying to learn mathematics again in a systematic way. I started reading book "Higher Algebra by Barnard and Child". After satisfying with concepts of first chapter (Theory of Numbers) , I started doing exercise and I don't know why I can't even solve first question of first exercise.

Question:

> If $q$ is the quotient and $r$ is the remainder when $a$ is divided by $b$, show that $q$ is the quotient when $a$ is divided by $b+1$, provided that $r \geq q$.

I can understand this intuitively but don't how to show. I'll be very glad if someone advice me whether I'm reading right book according to my level.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The key idea here is the [Euclidean division algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division#Statement_of_the_theorem). The hypothesis means $$a=bq+r$$ where $0\leq r<b$.

Therefore $$a+q=(b+1)q+r$$

So $$a=(b+1)q+r-q$$